# Drupal 7 - Node reference not autocomplete

Tags: php, drupal, reference, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I would like to have a node reference field as a text field with NO autocomplete. How can I get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)() to alter this form, and then unset the #autocomplete_path property from your text field.

Example:

```
unset($form['myfield']['#autocomplete_path']);
```